# How to pass env variables to Angular App on Jboss

Tags: environment-variables, angular5, jboss7.x

I have an Angular 5 application packaged as a war file and deployed on Jboss server. What is the best way to pass a parameter to the application? e.g. I want to pass environment as test , qa , prod based on the various environments. Based on the parameter passed I would like to use appropriate environment.ts file. On local it is easy to do just by ng serve --env test command since I am using http-server on local. However, that is not possible to do on Jboss. I do not think passing a JVM parameter will be an option. Please let me know your ideas.

Comment: For now I have created multiple wars for each environment. However I would prefer just one war so that the same war which got QA approval would go to prod.

Comment: I was able to do lazy loading implementation, so basically I am calling a webservice which returns me an API Key based on the env and use that key to assign to AngularGoogleMaps module. So when the application is loaded apiKey is not set (and not hard coded ) but later the APIKey is lazy loaded from webservice and assigned to AngularGoogleMaps module. This solution is working great for me.